# Chart related query: adding new category field manually

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a chart using SSRS 2008. I've got 4 category fields:

- field 1
- field 2
- field 3
- field 4

I want to add another category field in the chart which will be a total, e.g.:

```
field 1 + field 2 + field 3 + field 4
```

Now I don't know how to do it. Field 1 through field 4 come from a table directly, but because field 5 is the total I dont know how to add it manually?

In the Category field of the chart, I have used group on(column name) and want to add another field in the chart which will be the total.

I have even tried this :-

=Fields!ColumnName.Value.Equals("ABC")+Fields!ColumnName.Value.Equals("DEF")+Fields!ColumnName.Value.Equals("GHI")+Fields!ColumnName.Value.Equals("JKL")

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would select the chart object, then click it again so the Chart Data pane appears.

Then I would click the + button next to Values, then choose Expression.

In the Expression I would enter something like:

`= Fields!Field1.Value + Fields!Field2.Value + Fields!Field3.Value + Fields!Field4.Value`

Comment: Hi Mike. thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate bit more? I have used Category fields in my charts. In Category field, I have used group on (column name) which is working fine. I want to keep those fields + I want to add another category field in the chart which will be a total of field 1 to field 4.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your description now. Do you have 4 Category Groups (Field1-4)? If that is the case then I would go back to the Dataset and add a UNION with a GROUP BY to generate a total row.  I would overwrite the Field1-4 values with 'Total'.

Comment: Thanks Mike. you have solved my query. To add a UNION and GROUP By idea didn't come to my mind. I have tried it and new category field i.e.total is added into my charts. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go back to the Dataset and add a UNION with a GROUP BY to generate a total row. I would overwrite the Field1-4 values with 'Total'.